# Get the path to a local OrientDB?

Tags: orientdb

I am using OrientDB and run it locally. I know the path to it is "/temp/mydb" because that's the variable I hand down to the OrientGraph constructor. The full path would then be "plocal:/temp/mydb".

But how do I find out the drive/full path it was created on? (e.g. C:/temp/mydb)

I am using it via Java in case that matters.

**EDIT:** After some testing it seems like it depends on the drive the application was launched from. Any reliable way to find this out?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a relative path without specifying where you're starting, catching the current path is just going to return the folder of where your java program is:

```
File path = new File("test/mydb");
System.out.println(path.getAbsolutePath()); //C:\path\of\your\java\program\test\mydb
```

You can either pass it the full path manually or place your ODB inside your program's folder or viceversa.